# Select data from last week mysql query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a table with a datefield and  I want to select all the entries that came from the last week,Saturday to Sunday(not last 7 days).

Table values

```
Date               ID    Value
8/3/2015 8:03 PM    a     10        
8/4/2015 8:03 PM    b     20        
8/5/2015 8:03 PM    c     30    
8/6/2015 8:03 PM    d     40    
8/7/2015 8:03 PM    e     50    
8/9/2015 8:03 PM    f     60        
8/10/2015 8:03 PM   g     70
```

I only want to select id from last which are a,b,c,d,e. How do i write the mysql query in this ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @Bulat i have tried to used this SELECT *FROM StudentPurchasedHistoryTable WHERE [Purchased Date] >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) but it only display all of them

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky.  One method is to try something like `week()`, but that has a problem at the beginning of the year.

Another approach is to get the date of midnight on Sunday and use that for the calculation.  I think this expression does that:

```
 date_sub(curdate(), interval (weekday(curdate()) + 1) % 7) - 1 day)
```

You can then plug this into the `where` clause:

```
select v.*
from values v
where v.date < date_sub(curdate(), interval (weekday(curdate()) + 1) % 7) - 1 day) and
      v.date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval (weekday(curdate()) + 1) % 7) - 8 day);
```

Note:  this formulation can make use of an index on `date`.